# Internet Explorer 11- issue with security certificate error prompt

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I am testing a website in IE11. It has mixed content (http and https). In previous versions, there is a prompt which asks which we should allow the content with security certificate error. However no such prompt is displayed in IE11 and the site breaks. I tried changing the security settings in Advanced Options but it was of no use. Pls advice..

Comment: Just an observation; disabling certificate verification is in general not a good idea if the machine is used for anything more than testing. An option is to install something like [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) which will allow you to intercept HTTPS and ignore certificate errors just while it's running.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson ya it is for testing purpose only. Thanks for the suggestion regarding Fiddler.. That helped..

Answer (score 4):

This behavior is related to Zone that is set - *Internet/Intranet/etc* and corresponding Security Level

You can change this by setting less secure Security Level (*not recommended*) or by customizing **Display Mixed Content** property

You can do that by following steps:

1. Click on Gear icon at the top of the browser window.
2. Select Internet Options.
3. Select the Security tab at the top.
4. Click the Custom Level... button.
5. Scroll about halfway down to the Miscellaneous heading (denoted by a "blank page" icon).
6. Under this heading is the option **Display Mixed Content**; set this to Enable/Prompt.
7. Click OK, then Yes when prompted to confirm the change, then OK to close the Options window.
8. Close and restart the browser.

[image]

Comment: Just a warning that these settings may not be available for edit if you're on a company issued machine with group policy enforcement.

Comment: I'm trying to visit site where it says **There is a problem with this website’s security certificate.** and when I click visit the site a popup opens below saying **do you want to open or save**. When I click open nothing happens. Note I'm running win7 in virtualbox on macOS. Any ideas

Comment: It would be so much easier if this would be text file then you can use your editor to find the string "Display mixed content", instead of having to follow vague indications like "about halfway down to the Miscellaneous heading". Not your fault of course, just a short-coming of WIndows. +1

Answer (score -1):

If you updated Internet Explorer and began having technical problems, you can use the Compatibility View feature to emulate a previous version of Internet Explorer.

For instructions, see the section below that corresponds with your version. To find your version number, click Help > About Internet Explorer.
Internet Explorer 11

To edit the Compatibility View list:

```
Open the desktop, and then tap or click the Internet Explorer icon on the taskbar.
Tap or click the Tools button (Image), and then tap or click Compatibility View settings.
To remove a website:
Click the website(s) where you would like to turn off Compatibility View, clicking Remove after each one.
To add a website:
Under Add this website, enter the website(s) where you would like to turn on Compatibility View, clicking Add after each one.
```