# IE 11 Error: Issue with website’s security certificate

Tags: internet-explorer

I am using a IE 11 to test an application on my local machine which has address:

https://10.10.10.20/app.html

IE show ups a message:

```
There is a problem with this website’s security certificate.
```

I understand I can click:

```
"Continues to this website (not recommended)"
```

But I would need instead bypass this dialog, and see the content straight away.

Do you know if it is possible? How to do it?

Comment: Use a valid certificate, that's how.

Comment: Follow this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21966750/internet-explorer-11-issue-with-security-certificate-error-prompt

Comment: Also, check your date. If the date in your testing enviroment is not correct some browsers will fail to accept your certificate.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment I was able to solve this problem using:

- Open Internet Explorer.
- Select the options gear, then select
- “Internet Options“. Select the “Advanced” tab. Scroll down to the
  “Security” section, and uncheck the “Warn about certficate address
  mismatch” option.
- Select “OK“. Restart the computer.

If you know a better way, please post your answer.