# Widlfly 9 HTPPS configured, not accesible with Internet Explorer

Tags: java, internet-explorer, https, internet-explorer-11, wildfly-9

I have configured Wildfly 9 according to the instructions on this link:

[Wildfly 9 http to https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32008182/wildfly-9-http-to-https)

I can access my aplications using Chrome or Firefox (both warn me about the Self Signed certificate but allow to add the exception). When i try to access wildfly over https using Internet Explorer 11 it will not load, it shows the message:

The page cannot be shown

I have alredy tried adding the site as trusted, changed advanced configuration, registering DLLs clearing cache, etc. Nothing works. 
Anybody knows what could be happening? is there a way to find out what is preventing IE from accesing Wildfly?

Comment: I think its IE 11 issue, not because of wildfly 9. Please refer following link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21966750/internet-explorer-11-issue-with-security-certificate-error-prompt

Comment: I tried the the solutions presented in the post but still not working. I'll keep searching.